# Canceling future / stream / task, future collections handling

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm building a program in rust (nightly, async-await, futures-preview, tokio 0.2+) to record video from IP camera over RTSP.

Recorder module spawns ffmpeg process that creates video chunks. It also catches and logs stderr/stdout of ffmpeg and logs it to screen. In case of errors (network etc) ffmpeg may die, so I want to restart it after 15 seconds infinitely.

I would like to create dynamic Recorder**s** collection. I want to add / delete Recorders at runtime. At some point for each created Recorder I must obtain its future and pass it to `tokio::spawn`. From the black-box point of view I want the Recorders to provide two methods: `add(r: Recorder OR all recorder params) -> RecorderHandle` and `remove(rh: RecorderHandle)`.

- Is there any recommended pattern for such scenario?
- How can I delete the recorder? How can I cancel future passed to `tokio::spawn`?
- Where would dropped future stop? On nearest `.await`?
- Is `run()` method ok? Are there any suggestions?
- Is `run_infinite()` method ok?
- Are there any recommendations for infinite streams?

### Recorder code

```
pub struct RtspRecorder {
    rtsp_url: url::Url,
    segment_time: std::time::Duration,
    output_strftime: String,
    output_directory: std::path::PathBuf
}

impl RtspRecorder {
    pub fn new( /* just all fields are passed to the struct */ ) -> Self { /* (...) */}
    fn ffmpeg_command_build(&self) -> tokio_net::process::Command { /* sets env and command line arguments */ }

    pub async fn run(
        &self,
    ) -> Box<dyn std::error::Error> {
        let mut command = self.ffmpeg_command_build();
        let mut child = command.spawn().unwrap();

        let stdout = tokio::codec::FramedRead::new(child.stdout().take().unwrap(), tokio::codec::LinesCodec::default())
            .for_each(|message| { log::info!("ffmpeg stdout: {}", message.unwrap()); return futures::future::ready(()); });

        let stderr = tokio::codec::FramedRead::new(child.stderr().take().unwrap(), tokio::codec::LinesCodec::default())
            .for_each(|message| { log::warn!("ffmpeg stderr: {}", message.unwrap()); return futures::future::ready(()); });

        let futures_results = futures::future::join3(child, stdout, stderr).await;

        return match futures_results.0 {
            Err(e) => e.into(),
            Ok(exit_status) => format!("ffmpeg exited with status: {:?}", exit_status).into()
        }
    }

    pub async fn run_infinite(
        &self
    ) {
        loop {
            let error = self.run().await;
            log::warn!("error during run: {:?}, restarting...", error);
            tokio_timer::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_secs(15)).await;
        }
    }
}
```